# pep8 fail with fabric

Tags: python, fabric, pep8

I want to use python pep8 to inspect my code and generate reports about the quality of my app

I used it manually with the following command:

```
# In my app root directory
pep8 . > report.txt
```

This was generating a report.txt file with all PEP8 error detected by pep8

But now, I need to include it in a Fabric script. I just did that:

```
def test_pep8():
    env.run("pep8 . > report.txt")
```

When I run `test_pep8`, I have the following error and I don't know why :

```
(test)➜  fab test_pep8
    [localhost] Executing task 'test_pep8'
    [localhost] local: pep8 . > report.txt

    Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'pep8 . > report'
```

Do you know why I have such an error ? :( The file report is generated but this error code is stoping my fabric command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `pep8 .` returns non-zero error code which means it found warnings and the code didn't validate. And, according to fabric's [`Failure handling`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/execution.html#failure-handling):

> Fabric defaults to a “fail-fast” behavior pattern: if anything goes
>   wrong, such as a remote program returning a nonzero return value or
>   your fabfile’s Python code encountering an exception, execution will
>   halt immediately.

The solution would be to set `warn_only` to `True` and [`hide`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.hide) the error temporarily using [`settings` context manager](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings):

```
from fabric.context_managers import settings, hide

def test_pep8():
    with settings(hide('warnings', 'running', 'stdout', 'stderr'),
                  warn_only=True):
        env.run("pep8 . > report.txt")
```

Comment: Ok now I have a "Warning: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'pep8 . > report'" which seems better.

Comment: @AlexGrs okay, you need to `hide` the error too, please see the updated answer.